# Change the "ask on meta" links on the "ask question" page for Super User and Server Fault?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions, meta, per-site-meta

Now that there is a [Meta site for Super User and Server Fault](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/), what about the "ask on meta" links, on a [new question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask)?

Should they point to the new meta sites?

If so, it will probably increase the chances for questions about the framework itself, on the sub meta site, though.

Comment: Yes, they should IMO

Comment: Or they should be like all the other SE sites and not have a `ask on meta` link

Answer (score 1):

Done, and I also added a link to the /faq from the ask page title help.

This should have been on there for years.. not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score -2):

I disagree.

I would rather have this meta (meta.stackoverflow.com) be a catch-all for everything, and delegate to the sub-meta sites only when necessary.

- Most of the metaquestions are about the engine itself (note that feature requests can *only* belong on this meta), so I think there would be a lot of unnecessary migration going on from the sub-meta to this meta. This meta has more traffic, and more users who have the know-how and moderator abilities to sort through questions to determine their proper forum for answering.
- We don't want to miss out on a bug report because the question failed to get enough close/migration votes for whatever reason.
- The overall audience on this meta are going to be the most aware of new features/changes to the system, so if all the traffic for those questions is directed to the sub-meta sites, it could be total overwhelm either because of unawareness of the feature/change, or simply being so inundated that everyone runs out of close votes (there will be more traffic and fewer active users).

Simply introducing a sub-meta site will direct *some* questions to the wrong spot, and that's pretty much unavoidable, but I don't think we should try to put the onus completely on the users of the particular site.

Comment: I think you have this very backwards -- the community around a specific site needs to drive the functionality of *that* site based on the topic. In the rare case that they want a feature that's truly all-engine, then we could look at escalating upwards to the "national capital" from the "state capital". In other words, the state capitals should be concerned with state business as much as they can!

Comment: @Jeff: Yes, but at the same time you're downloading responsibilities to a more local level. If a feature drastically changes, there will be many duplications of questions across all sites, with the potential to *flood* the "national capital" with questions when migration is implemented.

Comment: I should mention that this answer probably doesn't belong in this question -- I disagree more with the system than with this specific feature request.